# Does Visual Studio 2019 community edition support MVC 5 projects?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2019

I wanted to start an MVC 5 project to follow a course, so I went to the Tools > Get Tools and Features. I can only see MVC 4 in the Individual components tab.

Does it mean I need to install different version of Visual Studio?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will come in as a nuget package (`System.Web.Mvc`) and not the Tools and Features installer of VS.

You'll require at least version 4.52 of .NET Framework (and I think) it would default to MVC 5.x by default (I could be wrong) but you can upgrade the nuget package manager and update it manually.

Answer (score 6):

You don't have to install any nuget package for that. Just create a new project in vs 2019 community and on project template selection page, select "ASP.NET Web Application (.Net Framework)". It will default to MVC5 project.

[Project Template Selection window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QT2YG.jpg)

You can check the mvc version later in web.config file.

```
<assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.7.0" newVersion="5.2.7.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
```

here you can see  assembly name and its version.